# fiddler is not showing raw data properly

Tags: javascript, html, post, https, fiddler

I am using latest fiddler 4.4.8.0 and have set it up to see https sessions.
However when I try to see the request / response payloads in "raw data" tab, all I see is garbage data.

please see the image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The image is too small for me to read and I can't make it any bigger. Is it me, or did you upload a tiny picture?

Comment: m sorry but this is fixed.  I just had to open the sessions in IE instead of chrome.  Looks like chrome has some issues.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Chrome vs. IE.

Perhaps you should click the giant yellow button which reads as follows:

`Response is encoded and may need to be decoded before inspection. Click here to transform.`

Alternatively, click the `Decode` button in Fiddler's toolbar to have Fiddler decompress and unchunk Sessions automatically as they are received.

Comment: Obviously I had tried that before posting the question (it was not that difficult to see that yellow button :-).  And it had not helped.  But when I changed the browser from chrome to IE its working fine.  From a black box testing perspective, I would say this has something to do with Fiddler and Chrome (the way it decodes that).

Answer (score 0):

When I used it with IE it started working.